# sstableloader - Not able to restore backups taken by OpsCenter using command line sstableloader

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I am trying to restore backups generated by OpsCenter on target cluster with different topology using sstableloader but sstableloader is not able to recognize backups taken by OpsCenter. There are no errors but files are not streamed.

```
sstableloader -d 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2,127.0.0.3 -v /backup/killrvideo/videos -u cassandra -pw xxxxxxxx

WARN  20:10:37,677 Only 51.247GiB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more 
capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
Established connection to initial hosts
Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream

Summary statistics: 
   Connections per host    : 1         
   Total files transferred : 0         
   Total bytes transferred : 0.000KiB  
   Total duration          : 5420 ms   
   Average transfer rate   : 0.000KiB/s
   Peak transfer rate      : 0.000KiB/s
```

/backup/killrvideo/videos folder has sstables files related to killrvideo.videos. File names were extracted from backup.json file

Next I tried to take backup using nodetool snapshot of same table. I coped files from snapshot folder of [data]/killrvideo/videos to my backup folder /backup/killrvideo/videos and then executed same sstableloader command and this time it was successful.

Does that mean backups taken by opscenter are not compatible with sstableloader ? What am I missing ? How to load backups of opscenter using command line sstableloader ?

sstableloader is from default location of datastax-dse installation : resources/cassandra/bin/sstableloader

DataStax Version : 6.8.25

Please advice.